# Load page in background?

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code embedded into a webpage which is intended to send the clients current time to the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function settime() 
{
   var d = new Date();
   var h = d.getHours();
   var m = d.getMinutes();
   $.get('settime.html?h='+h+'&m='+m, function(data, status)
   {
   });
}
</script>
 <body onload="settime();">
 ...
```

The idea: on loading of the body, JS-function settime() should be called which itself accesses the page "settime.html" with some parameters handed over.

The problem: settime.html is not called, there is never such a request at the server. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check for any errors in the console?

Comment: @AshikPaul indeed, it complains about "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       var d = new Date();
       var h = d.getHours();
       var m = d.getMinutes();
       $.get('settime.html?h='+h+'&m='+m, function(data, status)
       {
         //Handle Success Here
       });

});
```

This way as soon as the DOM has loaded Jquery will fire the `.ready` function which will run your code.

Comment: When using this code the console gives me an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Shouldn't I place this inside some script-tags outside of the body?

Comment: Yes, to use the $ functions for JQuery you need to use JQuery Script from JQuery.com and also place the code inside <script> </script> tags